# Java - why is the performance of my platformer game so low?

Tags: java, performance

I'm currently working on a platformer game in java, and I'm having trouble figuring out why this decreases performance so much. Only the textures in view of the camera are rendered, and I've even tried clearing all objects outside the camera's view, so that the array was almost empty, and I still was unable to get a good framerate. When I comment out the call to this method, the game runs at 300 FPS, but when I run it, even when I remove everything afterwords, I still only get 40 FPS. This is not an issue with rendering, as I have tested this thoroughly. Any feedback would be much appreciated. Here is the code:

```
public void buildTerrain(BufferedImage bi) {
    // this method will take an image and build a level based on it.
    int width = bi.getWidth();
    int height = bi.getHeight();
    for(int x = 0; x < width; x++){
        for(int y = 0; y < height; y++){
            int pixel = bi.getRGB(x, y);
            int r = (pixel >> 16) & 0xff;
            int g = (pixel >> 8) & 0xff;
            int b = (pixel) & 0xff;
            if(r == 255 &&
                g == 255 &&
                b == 255)
                h.addObject(new Block(x*32, y*32,
                ID.blockStone,GameState.level1, tex));
            if(r == 0 &&
                g == 0 &&
                b == 255){
                p.setX(x*32);
                p.setY(y*32);
                p.setHeight(64);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

references:
h is a Handler object, witch contains a method addObject(GameObject)
Block extends GameObject
p is a Player, witch also extends GameObject.

EDIT: this code is not called in a loop, it is ran once at the beginning of each level to load the terrain. All the AddObject() method does is add the Blocks to an array where then are then iterated over in the tick() and render() methods. Only objects in the scope of the camera are rendered, and the tick() method of blocks is empty.

Comment: Drawing/reading pixels individually is very costly, try to avoid that. If possible (since this is basically just loading a map?) try to do this only once.

Comment: Think about what things can cause a 7.5x slowdown. You said that the game runs at 300 fps without the call to `buildTerrain`, but only at 40fps with the call. It sounds like this call is being called more frequently than you would like or is more computationally expensive than you expected. Try to load the map once and make only small changes as needed.

Comment: Either @callyalater is right, the method is just called too often, or I would suspenct the method addObject is slow on the 'h' object. What is 'h' by the way?

Comment: I don't think we can debug this just from being shown a single loop.  I'd like to see an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can diagnose exactly where the problem.  There's too many possible reasons why you may be seeing a slowdown.

Comment: This question probably belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Use the profiler to find out what the bottleneck is.

Comment: this is not looped, it is called once at the beginning of each level. The GameObjects are ticked and rendered separately.

Comment: You say *addObject add the Block to an array*. Should we assume the array is already initialized, and you do something like `array[nextBlock++] = block` ... and not something like `List<> list = new ArrayList<>(asList(array)); list.add(block); array = list.toArray(...);` ?

Comment: So you say if you don't call it, render() doesn't iterate on "Blocks" added to the handler and it works much faster? Sounds like whatever it does with the Blocks takes too much time or maybe does some "new"s which overload the GC. There might be many things happening, run profiler like it was suggested (jvisualvm.exe) with and then without the method. You should see CPU time, GC time or other differences. (also make sure it really runs once).

Comment: @TyEverett Does that mean your question is "If my level is empty, I get 300fps, but if I load the terrain it drops to 40fps, why?"...I'm not terribly surprised to hear that a 3d engine runs 7.5x slower when it has things to paint than when it has nothing at all to paint. But with regard to the engine's performance, is it considering whether a block will be visible before painting it, or is only range considered? Is it drawing faces of blocks that cannot be seen? Where is the performance hotspot when sampling CPU with jVisualVM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try:

```
    if(0xffffff00 == (pixel & 0xffffff00))
        h.addObject(new Block(x*32, y*32,
        ID.blockStone,GameState.level1, tex));
    if(0x0000ff00 == (pixel & 0x0000ff00)){
        p.setX(x*32);
        p.setY(y*32);
        p.setHeight(64);
    }
```

Because I don't understand the need of decomposing (r, g, b) for each pixel while you can do that using a binary `&` (0xffffff00, it might be 0x00ffffff).

- in your code, you do `width*height*(3 shift + 3 and + 3 equals + 3 equals)` operations.
- in my code, you do `width*height*2*(and + test)` operations.